# How to open a directory within a directory in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to read files that are in one directory, but the directory has another directory that has information that I also need to read. Anyone has an idea of how I can do that? Here's my directory tree

```
Root
   |__code
        |__ file.rb (where I am working from)
   |__Directory
      |__file 1
      |__file 2
      |__Directory 2
                 |__file 3
                 |__file 4
```

I'm using `File.open("file1", "r")` to open the files.

Comment: I assume you are running the script from within `Directory`. Did you try, for example, `File.open("Directory2/file3", "r")`?

Comment: @lurker no, I'm working in another directory called code, I have edited the tree.

Comment: The question text does not make it clear if you want to read all files that happen to be in the directory tree or some predefined file such as `Root/Directory/Directory2/file3`.

Comment: @LindaKadz if that's teh case, then `File.open("file1", "r")` won't necessarily work either. You'll need to work with a more explicit path.

Answer (score 1):

Dir.glob is what you need. From [Ruby Doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Dir.html#glob-method):

> Expands pattern, which is a pattern string or an Array of pattern
>   strings, and returns an array containing the matching filenames. If a
>   block is given, calls the block once for each matching filename,
>   passing the filename as a parameter to the block.

```
files = File.join("Root", "Directory", "**", "*")
Dir.glob(files)
# => ["Root/Directory/file 1", "Root/Directory/file 2", "Root/Directory 2/file 3", "Root/Directory 2/file 4"]
```

Comment: what's the first argument in the `File.join` method?

Comment: I figured out what the first arguement is, I put the path to `Directory` and it listed for me all the files in the directory (that's `file 1 and file 2`), but not `Directory 2`. In fact, here's my output  ` # [ "../Directory 1/file1.rb", "../Directory 1/file2.rb", "../Directory 1/file3.rb", "../Directory 1/file4.rb"]`

Comment: @LindaKadz I've just updated the answer to reflect the changes to the question. Please add the code you have been trying

Comment: This worked very well, but then I refactored to `Dir.glob("../Directory 1/**/*.rb")` Thanks so much!